# Conversion between timestamp to milliseconds in DB2

Tags: db2, timestamp

I have a column of datatype timestamp. Now I need to convert it to MiiliSeconds and put in another column. How can I do that. 
the input is of the format `2011-10-04 13:54:50.455227` and the output needs to be `1317900719`

Comment: Hi, when you say you want to convert it to Milliseconds; Milliseconds from what value? is it compared to another timestamp column or a constant timestamp value or take only the Milliseconds part from the same timestamp column?

Comment: Edited the question with the formats.

Comment: I don't get how you're getting that desired output. I would expect that if you wanted ms, that you'd at least end with 50455.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function called timestampdiff. Using it against January 1st 1970 would work otherwise but the function gives approximate results. If you want accuracy you will want to calculate the correct answer with something like

```
create function ts2millis(t timestamp)
returns bigint
return (
 ( 
  (bigint(year(t-1970))*bigint(31556926000))+
  (bigint(month(t))*bigint(2629743000))+
  (bigint(day(t))*bigint(86400000))+
  (bigint(hour(t))*bigint(3600000))+
  (bigint(minute(t))*bigint(60000))+
  (bigint(second(t))*bigint(1000))+
  (bigint(microsecond(t))/bigint(1000))
 )
)
@
```

Comment: Different months have different number of days (aka milliseconds), so you can't use a fixed value. Especially since February has different values depending on the year.

Answer (score 1):

Your requested output is not miliseconds, but the equivalent to CLib localtime(), here's how to do it:

```
SELECT
    86400*
    (
        DAYS(TIMESTAMP(v_timestamp))
        -
        DAYS(TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01-00:00:00'))
    )
    +
    MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(timestamp(v_timestamp))
FROM
    SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

where `v_timestamp` is the variable or column to be calculated.